# How do I delete emoji suggestions on LG Stylo 2 Plus?

Tags: delete, emoticons

I do not want emojis to be suggested after I have used them. I have tried finding a clear cache or clear data option through the LG Keyboard but am unable to find anything that would allow me to do this.

Is it possible to delete emoji suggestions on the LG Stylo 2 Plus? If so, please give step by step instructions. Thank you.